# Does running time for one thread is same for running time of 1000 threads in python multi-threading?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

While trying the below python code which illustrates the multi-threading concept,it took 0.8 sec.

```
import time
import threading

def calc_square(numbers):
    print("calculate square numbers")
    for n in numbers:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print('square:',n*n)

def calc_cube(numbers):
    print("calculate cube of numbers")
    for n in numbers:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print('cube:',n*n*n)

arr = [2,3,8,9]

t = time.time()


t1= threading.Thread(target=calc_square, args=(arr,))
t2= threading.Thread(target=calc_cube,args=(arr,))

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()

print("done in : ",time.time()-t,"seconds")
```

Here 2 threads are created each of each function. If again we are creating threads like t3,t4...t10 it took same 0.8 sec. Does this will be same for 1000 threads?
 Since for loop in python is not parallel, we cant use for loop for running this.

```
  for i in range(1000):
    t1= threading.Thread(target=calc_square, args=(arr,))
    t1.start()
    t1.join()
```

could not be used. So my doubt is, is that same 0.8 sec for 1000 threads?

Comment: My guess it, it should be depending what system resources thread are using. Based on resource availability and system load this time should vary.

Comment: @Stepen Actually that 0.2 s sleep time is used by other threads to execute.